# Using regex to map values in dataframe using python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, mapping

have a df with values :

```
name   number     addition

tom    123        this is tom , number is [[number]]
mark   1234       this is mark , number is [[number]]
```

using regex how to map  value in number column with  [[number]] in addition column like this

```
name   number     addition

tom    123        this is tom , number is 123
mark   1234       this is mark , number is 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apply`:

```
df['addition'] =  df.apply(lambda row: row['addition'].replace('[[number]]', str(row['number'])), axis=1)
```